# tricky dependent pattern match without axioms

Tags: coq, dependent-type

Suppose I have the following type:

```
Inductive foo : Type -> Type :=
  | A : forall X, Empty_set -> foo X
  | B : foo unit.
```

Can I prove the following:

```
Lemma obv : forall x : foo unit, x = B.
```

without axioms?  The `dependent destruction` tactic takes care of it pretty easily, but that introduces the axiom `JMeq_eq`.  I found [this](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/dep-destruct.html) article, but it doesn't seem applicable in this case, since `Type` doesn't have UIP.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like one needs either `JMeq_eq` or `UIP` to prove this. [It would be cool if someone proved me wrong ;)]

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not provable without something like univalence or UIP.  The type `foo unit` is isomorphic to the type `unit = unit`, so proving that all inhabitants of `foo unit` are equal to `B` is the same as proving that all inhabitants of `unit = unit` are equal to `eq_refl`, and this cannot be proven without axioms, in Coq.